# Align environment immediately after section break

Tags: amsmath

When I use an align environment immediately after a new section, there is a significantly increased line break between the section and the equation, too large for my taste. Is there a way to make this break the same size as if text were immediately after the section break?

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{F at the critical point}
    \label{sec:1fi}

    \begin{align*}
        F(a)&=\frac{1}{2}
    \end{align*}

    The second derivative test has been to chosen in order to confirm the nature of the critical point:

    \begin{align*}
        F''(a)&=8+\frac{9}{2a^4}+\frac{5}{4a^6}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Additionally, there is more space than I would like between the text and the second align, as compared to between the first align and the text.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is alsways \vspace*{-\baselineskip}

Comment: @JohnKormylo  Which is not a good thing to teach new users (some of us spend loads of time removing that sort of constructions from manuscripts). It might be better to know why a section is started with a displayed formula. This is normally never seen in any regular math text.

Comment: Is there a reason for *not* having some text between the section header and the `align` environment? Is the section header sufficiently self-explanatory to make text unnecessary?

Comment: @Mico The document is an assignment in a question-answer format, so the header is sufficient explanation for the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the additional space was caused by the line breaks - commenting these lines out solves this issue ([Spacing around align environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/spacing-around-align-environments/198615#198615)). `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` is sufficient when the environment follows a section header.