# Spacing around align environments

Tags: amsmath

I first learnt to use LaTeX using the equation environment, and liked to set out my .tex document with spacing around equations. Now that I use the align environment, putting this additional space before an align will make a large space in my document (compared to a barely noticeable space), which I do not like. Is there a way to edit aligns so that they have behave similarly to equations in this respect?

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    \begin{equation*}
        a+b=c
    \end{equation*}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    \begin{align*}
        a+b=c
    \end{align*}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text 

    \begin{equation*}
        a+b=c
    \end{equation*}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text 

    \begin{align*}
        a+b=c
    \end{align*}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you interested in an automated way to *always* remove any vertical space prior/after an `align` environment?

Comment: The same is true of `equation` you should never leave a blank line before an equation environment, it makes a blank line that looks like extra vertical space but is actually a line box and will not be discarded even at the top of a page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not leave empty lines before and after environments like `equation` `align` etc to keep the spacing consistent. If you want your code to be more readable, you may put a `%` instead of blank line. For example see the following and compare your out put with this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \begin{equation*}
        a+b=c
    \end{equation*}
     %
    text text text text text text text text text text text text
    \begin{align*}
        a+b=c
    \end{align*}
    %
    text text text text text text text text text text text text
    %
    \begin{equation*}
        a+b=c
    \end{equation*}
    %
    text text text text text text text text text text text text
    %
    \begin{align*}
        a+b=c
    \end{align*}
    %
    text text text text text text text text text text text text


\end{document}
```

[image]

These environments add `\abovedisplayskip` above and `belowdisplayskip` below (there is also `\abovedisplayshortskip`...) If you leave empty spaces, these spaces will be added to the `\parskip` and you are bound to get inconsistent spacing.

*Don't add blank lines before and after*